# A function with variables and parameters as arguments of fminunc function

Tags: matlab, convex-optimization, fminsearch

I am trying to use fminunc function in matlab to solve an unconstrained minimization problem. This function has the format

```
[x,f] = fminunc (@fun,x0);
```

Here, the defined fun is an input of fminunc as an objective function. However, my fun function has the format as follow

```
[fval] = fun (x1,x2,a,b,c)
```

where $x1$ and $x2$ are vector variables to solve and $a$,$b$ and $c$ are only parameters. I wrote my code as follow to solve this problem,

```
L = @(x1,x2)fun(x1,x2,a,b,c)
x0 = [x10; x20];
[x,f] = fminunc(L,x0);
```

However, it got errors saying 'The input arguments are not enough'. Does anyone have any ideas on why this happened?

Comment: In which exact line the error is occurring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation does not work, since you are supposed to submit a function that depends on a vector `x`, rather than a bunch of variables x1, x2.

You should replace you function definition by the following:

```
 L = @(x)fun(x,a,b,c)
```

In the function definition use x(1) and x(2) rather than x1 and x2.